# Proving an Stabilizer is the whole group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of $143$ elements acting on a set $X$ of $108$ elements. I need to prove that there is one element whose Stabilizer is the whole group.

I have tried doing it using the Orbits Equation, using that the possible indexes for the stabilizer are $1,11$ and $13$, but since I don't have any information on the set of unmoved objects I don't really know how to proceed.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, the possible sizes for an orbit are $1, 11$ and $13$.

If there was not an element whose stabiliser was the whole group, then there would be no orbit of size $1$, so the $108$ elements would need to be partitioned into orbits of sizes $11$ and $13$.

But you can't split $108$ up into pieces of size $11$ and $13$ (there are not a lot of cases to check), so there must be an orbit of size $1$.

Comment: Oh I see it now, thanks very much that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of each orbit equals the index of the stabilizer of a point in that orbit, so as you say the possible indices for the stabilizer are $1$, $11$, and $13$, and these are the possible cardinalities of each orbit (the other alternative $143$ is ruled out for being larger than $108$). The orbits partition the set $X$. Arguing by contradiction, if there is no element whose stabilizer is the whole group then all the orbits have cardinality $11$ and $13$, and therefore $108$ can be partitioned as $m \times 11 + n \times 13$ for some integers $m,n \ge 0$. But an exhaustive search shows this is impossible.